# Split column by last delimiter AND uppercase values - python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I'm trying to split a column by the last `' - '` **AND** being followed by all uppercase strings letters.

**It may not necessarily be the last delimiter in isolation. But it will be the last before all uppercase strings**.

I can find separate questions that separate based on first/last delimiter. But not with a combination.

Below, I have a df with `Value` containing various combinations. I want to split the col into two individuals columns, whereby, everything before the last `' - '` and uppercase letters.

I've got `Last` column correct but not `First` column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Value': ['Juan-Diva - HOLLS', 'Carlos - George - ESTE BAN - BOM', 'Javier Plain - Hotham Ham - ALPINE', 'Yul - KONJ KOL MON'],
   })
```

option 1)

```
df[['First', 'l']] = df['Value'].str.split(' - ', n=1, expand=True)

df['Last'] = df['Value'].str.split('- ').str[-1]
```

option 2)

```
# Regular expression pattern
pattern = r'^(.*) - ([A-Z\s]+)$'

# Extract groups into two new columns
df[['First', 'Last']] = df['Value'].str.extract(pattern)
```

option 3)

```
df[["First", "Last"]] = df["Value"].str.rsplit(" - ", n=1, expand=True)
```

None of these options return the intended output.

intended output:

```
                       First            Last
0                  Juan-Diva           HOLLS
1            Carlos - George  ESTE BAN - BOM
2  Javier Plain - Hotham Ham          ALPINE
3                        Yul    KONJ KOL MON
```

regex:

```
df[["First", "Last"]] = df["Value"].str.extract(r'(.*?)\s*-\s*([A-Z]+(?:\s*-?\s*[A-Z]+)*)')
```

```
                                Value         First          Last
0                   Juan-Diva - HOLLS          Juan             D
1    Carlos - George - ESTE BAN - BOM        Carlos             G
2  Javier Plain - Hotham Ham - ALPINE  Javier Plain             H
3                  Yul - KONJ KOL MON           Yul  KONJ KOL MON
```

Comment: Given a string `"Carlos - George - ESTE BAN - BOM"`, `"ESTE BAN - BOM"` does not follow the last `" - "`, nor is it composed only of uppercase letters.

Comment: How else would you word the question. I've been pretty explicit with the last delimiter being not necessarily the last in isolation. But it is the last before being followed by all uppercase strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `str.extract` here:

```py
df[["First", "Last"]] = df["Value"].str.extract(r'(.*?)\s*-\s*([A-Z]+(?:\s*-?\s*[A-Z]+)*)$')
```

### Demo

The above uses the 2/multicolumn version of `str.extract`.  It captures the first name in the first capture group.  It matches until hitting the nearest hyphen which is followed by all caps.  Then it matches the last name in the second capture group.

Comment: Yes it does.  Check the regex demo.

Comment: Might need a faster solution. Only 1000 rows and still running after 4 hours.

Comment: My answer was geared towards data analysis, not processing large production data sets.  I suggest doing this processing before you bring your data into Python.